# Gatekeeper blocks seemingly valid app

Tags: cocoa, codesign

I have a .prefPane that should be installed into System Preferences. When I double click it, Gatekeeper is blocking it saying it is not from an identified developer.

This error happens on 10.11.4, but it works on 10.10.5. Both OSes are brand new clean installs.

I reviewed TN2206 here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html

On my clean 10.11.4 system, I run:

```
codesign --verify --deep --verbose=2 path/to/my.prefPane
```

and get

```
My.prefPane: valid on disk
My.prefPane: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Then I run:

```
spctl -a -t exec -vv path/to/my.prefPane
```

and get

```
source=obsolete resource envelope
origin=Developer ID Application: MyCompany
```

then

```
codesign -dv path/to/my.prefPane
```

returns

```
Executable=/My.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/MyPrefPane
Identifier=com.myidentifier
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=1798 flags=0x0(none) hashes=82+3 location=embedded
Signature size=8557
Timestamp=Apr 6, 2016, 9:09:52 AM
Info.plist entries=33
TeamIdentifier=MYTEAMCODE
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=520
Internal requirements count=1 size=228
```

If I run the same file on my main 10.11.3 everything works fine. What could be happening here? The file was signed on my main 10.11.3 system.

Comment: Did you read specifically about the note on @rpath? I had an app that was linked against some dylibs that had rpaths that were outside of the app bundle and Gatekeeper would refuse to run the app.  Check your Console output when trying to open the pref pane and see if it says anything about rPathCmd failing.

Comment: Nothing about rPath. My "Other Linker Flags" are: -lstdc++.6 -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../Frameworks

Comment: And nothing gets logged to Console when you try opening the prefPane and get the Gatekeeper error?

Comment: Nope. I have a hunch that Sparkle is causing this. My PrefPane has several helper apps in there. When I run "spctl -a -t exec -vv" on one of them, I get nested code is modified or invalid. But I can't see how it is getting modified anywhere.

Comment: I have now gotten to the point where the internal helper apps (which are bundles) pass the test with "spctl -a -t exec -vv". But the internal helper tool that is a command-line tool gives "rejected/obsolete resource envelope" Is there a different way I need to sign command line tools? I tried not signing it and I get the same error on the enclosing prefPane

Comment: the same `codesign` tool should be fine for signing command line apps. When you do an archive build and you get the pref pane in the organizer, do you export and code sign again? That's the process I use and it works for me.

Comment: I am signing with a script because I have to sign the internal helper apps, do a checksum on them, then put that somewhere where the enclosing app can get to it, and finally sign the enclosing app. This all worked fine on 10.4... 10.10. I sign the command line tool the same way as the others. Is there a way to tell where the "resource envelope" is failing?

Comment: Is seems that signing a unix command line tool breaks. I created a simple command line tool in Xcode (Hello world) and signed it with my Developer ID on 10.11.3. It works fine. BUT... if I copy it to 10.11.4 and run spctl, I get an obsolete resource error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108560/discussion-between-aaron-and-trygve).

Comment: I just got a Hazel update's release notes which mention that Apple broke Gatekeeper in 10.11.4. See here (unless you are actually Hazel's developer!)

`New installer. Previously, Hazel was provided as a pref pane file that when double-clicked would launch System Preferences to install it. Unfortunately, Apple broke Gatekeeper in 10.11.4 where it (incorrectly) rejects any non-app software even when properly signed. Since the installer (being an app) is allowed by Gatekeeper, it will hand off the pref pane to System Preferences to continue the installation.`